# Show the location in Google Maps from a label

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

I have a **label** where **includes a value of address**. I want this address to be loaded in my google maps. The "prefered" solution is here [Plases Search](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox). But i don`t want this soloution. I dont want to search adreeses or stores or anything else. **I just want my label value to be loaded in my google maps**.

I would really appreciate any help! Thank you!

p.s. I have tried that solution but dont regonized some codes like `var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(search);`The **error** says:  *"Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined"*

Update:

```
<script>
        var map;
        var defaultLocation = { lat:37.977791, lng: 23.672878} ;
        var infoWindow;
        var marker;

        function initMap() {

            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                center: defaultLocation,
                zoom: 15
            });

            infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({map: map});

            //  HTML5 Geolocation.
            if (navigator.geolocation) {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
                var pos = {
                        lat: position.coords.latitude,
                        lng: position.coords.longitude
                };
                defaultLocation = pos;

                infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
                infoWindow.setContent('<h4> You are here! </h4>');
                map.setCenter(pos);
                }, function() {  //Geolocation service failed
                    handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
                    });
            } else {
                    // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
                    handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
                }
                //END HTML5 Geolocation.

            document.getElementById('add-marker').addEventListener('click', addMarker);
            document.getElementById('delete-marker').addEventListener('click', removeMarker);
        }

        //---->Here the problem!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        var search = document.getElementById('search');
        var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(search);

        searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
            var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

            if (places.length == 0) {
                return;
            }
        });

        // Geolocation Function
        function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow, pos) {
            infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
            infoWindow.setContent(browserHasGeolocation ?
                '<strong>Error:</strong> The Geolocation service failed.' :
                '<strong>Error:</strong> Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.');
        }

        // Add Marker
        function addMarker() {

            if (infoWindow){
                infoWindow.close();
            }

            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: map.getCenter(),
                draggable: true,
                map: map
            });
            updateCurrentLatLng(marker.getPosition());
            document.getElementById('add-marker').disabled = true;
            marker.addListener('dragend', updateCurrentLatLng);


        }

        // Delete Marker
        function removeMarker() {
            marker.setMap(null);
            document.getElementById('add-marker').disabled = false;
            document.getElementById('latcoords').value =null;
            document.getElementById('loncoords').value = null;
        }



        // Update the position of the marker in latitude and longitude
        function updateCurrentLatLng(latLng){
            document.getElementById('latcoords').value = marker.getPosition().lat();
            document.getElementById('loncoords').value = marker.getPosition().lat();
        }


    </script>
```

Comment: Post some code please @Rafsonic

Comment: What do you mean by a "label"?

Comment: You just want to put `label value` in `Google map SearchBox`  ? @Rafsonic

Comment: Yes only that! @simon

Comment: like a text box.... but value is already exist. dont neaded to search anything @geocodezip

Comment: Have you try replace this `var search=document.getElementById('search');` by `var search=document.getElementById('search').textContent;`  ? @Rafsonic

Comment: but the problem is not there... server dont regonized this code: `new google.maps.places.SearchBox(search);` @simon

Comment: have you include `google map places librairies` in you `HTML` ? @Rafsonic

Comment: the only thing that i added is `&libraries=places` next to my API KEY @simon

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the SearchBox initialization inside the initMap function.  Currently it is running before the input with id="search" has been rendered in the DOM.

```
function initMap() {

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: defaultLocation,
    zoom: 15
  });

  infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    map: map
  });
  //  HTML5 Geolocation.
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var pos = {
        lat: position.coords.latitude,
        lng: position.coords.longitude
      };
      defaultLocation = pos;

      infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
      infoWindow.setContent('<h4> You are here! </h4>');
      map.setCenter(pos);
    }, function() { //Geolocation service failed
      handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
    });
  } else {
    // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
    handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
  }
  //END HTML5 Geolocation.

  document.getElementById('add-marker').addEventListener('click', addMarker);
  document.getElementById('delete-marker').addEventListener('click', removeMarker);

  var search = document.getElementById('search');
  var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(search);

  searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
    var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

    if (places.length == 0) {
      return;
    }
  });
} // end of initMap
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/brhchyem/2/)

Comment: If this solved your problem, please [accept it](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)